# Can I work from Turkey temporarily for a US employer (Telework)?

Tags: turkey

My wife needs to be in Turkey for her PhD research for about 3 years.

I talked my employer saying that I want to work from Turkey around 6 months every year during that 3 year period. They refused me allowing working from Turkey. They stated that there will be tax implications with Turkish government and they dont have any offices there to build that relationship for an employee.

This really didnt make much sense to me considering I would be there 2-3 month periods twice a year. My taxes still will be paid to US and I don't need to declare anything to Turkey because I have dual citizenship (I wouldn't need a Turkish visa to stay there).

Can anyone help me to elaborate my issue to prove my employer that I can work there with no legal consequences?

I can also seek legal help if you can provide a good lawyer on this.

Comment: I don't know about Turkish law in particular (hence no answer) but your employer's position makes perfect sense to me, in principle. You might need to pay taxes in the US… but that does not mean you don't owe any taxes in Turkey. Your citizenship also takes care of a host of other problems and makes it munch easier to get away with breaking the rules but there is no direct link between visa and taxes. By default, you can also be liable to pay taxes wherever you actually perform the work. At least that's how it works in the countries I know.